# Apache Solr search against different combinations of text entered.

Tags: apache, solr

I am new to this Apache Solr. I want to do a search against different combinations of text entered. For example, if the text is 'hello' , it should return records having  hello,llo,hel,ollhe, he and so on..Is this possible with solr ? if so, how we can do this? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible in solr. You can use the `EdgeNGramFilterFactory` in your fieldType. here is the example of it.

Here word hello will have tokens like he, hel, hell and hello

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

or you can try `NGramTokenizerFactory` instead of `EdgeNGramFilterFactory`.

```
<tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="10"/>
```

Which will give the output like

for hello it would generate token like

he, hel, hell, hello, el, ell, and so..

Comment: Thank you for this update. I want to do this search against multiple columns. For example, if  i have name , address columns. search should happen against both these columns for different combinations of a text entered. Is this also possible with solr.? please help.

Comment: @Niranjan : Yes ..this possible ...for all those fields like name , address ...you have to apply the above fieldtype ...then you can achieve the desired result...If this helps ..please accept the answer

Comment: Thank you Abhijith..Let me check how this work for me.. I have just started to working on this..

Comment: I have defined fields in schema as follows: 'code'                                                                      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<schema name="autoSolrSchema" version="1.5">

<fields>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="xxxxxx" stored="true" type="StrField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="yyyyyy" stored="true" type="StrField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="aaaaaa" stored="true" type="StrTokenizer"/>

</fields>
<uniqueKey>(xxxxxx,yyyyyy,aaaaaa)</uniqueKey>
</schema>

Comment: Then I have defined fieldTypes under types as follows:       <fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.StrField" name="StrField"/><fieldType name="StrTokenizer" class="solr.TextField"><analyzer><tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="5"/></analyzer></fieldType><fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TrieFloatField" name="TrieFloatField"/><fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TextField" name="TextField"><analyzer><tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/></analyzer>
</fieldType>

Comment: <fieldType name="xxxxxx" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>

Comment: then  select?q=xxxxxx%3A11345&wt=json&indent=true query returns 67 records.. but  select?q=xxxxxx%3A11&wt=json&indent=true query returns 0 records... What is wrong in my schema..     @Abhijith Bashetti Please help me

Comment: @Niranjan : it would be good if you share the full schema.xml. but yes whats I see wrong is ....you have defined the fieldType but not used for your fields...

Comment: I have shared the schema fully.Please look into this and help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<schema name="autoSolrSchema" version="1.5">
<types>
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.StrField" name="StrField"/>
<fieldType name="StrTokenizer" class="solr.TextField">
<analyzer>
<tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="2"     maxGramSize="5"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TrieFloatField"  name="TrieFloatField"/>
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TextField" name="TextField">
<analyzer>
<tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
<fieldType name="user_id" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
<analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15"/>
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
</types>
<fields>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="user_id" stored="true" type="StrField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="company" stored="true" type="StrField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="tins" stored="true" type="TrieFloatField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="user_standard" stored="true" type="StrTokenizer"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="requests" stored="true" type="TrieFloatField"/>
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="include" stored="true" type="TextField"/>
</fields>
<uniqueKey>(user_id,company,user_standard)</uniqueKey>
</schema>
```

Comment: **@Abhijit Bashetti**  : I am posting entire schema as answer. Please look into this. I have defined two field types, among them one is specifically for user_id field. Please correct me where I am wrong

Comment: I see two field Types defined by you StrTokenizer and user_id.

Your user_id field is using StrField fieldType and not the one defined by you...

Comment: @Abhijit Bashetti:  Now i have referred the type user_id for the field user_id as below: <field indexed="true" multiValued="false" name="user_id" stored="true" type="user_id "/> .  But now it is working  as described below:

Comment: @Abhijit Bashetti: if user_id have value in document as 234a56xx, if we are searching for the texts 2,23,234,234a,234a5,234a56,234a56x,234a56xx then it will return records. just for one direction ordered tokens, i am getting records. But my requirement is like , search should be against almost similar document data, and here for this example ,even i am entering 56, this record should be fetched regardless of any order and position. Simply just like google kind of search. Please help how we can achieve this.

Comment: @Abhijit Bashetti : Thank you. now  I got it,  I have replaced the tokenizer class with solr.NGramTokenizerFactory. It worked for the expected results. Is there any way to list out almost similar searched values at the very top? Please help.

Comment: Thats the another question...YOu need accept this then we will move ahead with another one...:)...but yes read about boosting in solr....still have question we are here for you...

Comment: Sure. No issues to accept as your answer is worked for me :) It helps a lot. But I have more questions on these and i will post it as different questions. Please respond and help for them.